# Need a guide on Eclipse + Weblogic for developing Java EE web application

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I am newbie in Weblogic (but familiar with tomcat).

I have installed **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Helios)**.

I have installed **Oracle WebLogic Server 11g Rel 1 (10.3.4) Installers**

I am developing a Java EE web application in Eclipse, I am wondering is there any tutorial on how to use Weblogic server inside Eclipse? Something like Weblogic plugin for Eclipse and it's usage tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

The plugin you are looking for is called Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE). Find download links and tutorials at this location:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html